# Why this python while loop is becoming infinite

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I am learning Python and below is a a python game function which contains a while loop, but this loop is working as a infinite loop and I am unable to understand how it is working and how should it work.

Can anyone please help me to explain the while loop meaning here,and what is the relation between the "bear_move=False" variable and the loop condition "WHILE TRUE". I am unable to understand this while loop construct and condition here and with which this while loop condition is related.

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved=False

    while True:            #What is this while loop means here
        next=raw_input("You should write take honey or taunt bear: >")

    if next=="take honey":
        print "The bear looks at you then pimp slaps your face off."
    elif next=="taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
        print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
        bear_moved=True
    elif next=="taunt bear" and bear_moved:
        print "The bear gets pissed off and chews your crotch off."
    elif next=="open door" and bear_moved:
        gold_room()
    else:
        print "I got not I dea what that means."
```

Comment: Because `while True` is how you write an infinite loop.

Comment: For the sub-question, 'what is the relation between the "bear_move=False" variable and the loop condition "WHILE TRUE"': There is no relationship whatsoever (except that one comes after the other in the same function). `True` is a constant, not affected in any way by the value of `bear_moved`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` is outside of the loop, in python, indentation matters:

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved=False

    while True:            #What is this while loop means here
        next=raw_input("You should write take honey or taunt bear: >")

    # here you have to move all your block to the 
    # right, so it would be inside the while loop

        if next=="take honey":
            print "The bear looks at you then pimp slaps your face off."
        elif next=="taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved=True
        elif next=="taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            print "The bear gets pissed off and chews your crotch off."
        elif next=="open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got not I dea what that means."
```

Basically what it does, it reads input in the infinite cycle and does some action depending on this action. You can add `exit` command to your cycle so you can quit in any moment:

```
        if next=="take honey":
            print "The bear looks at you then pimp slaps your face off."
        elif next=="taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved=True
        elif next=="taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            print "The bear gets pissed off and chews your crotch off."
        elif next=="open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        elif next=="exit":
            break        # exit from cycle
        else:
            print "I got not I dea what that means."
```

Comment: Does the indentation of comments matter?  (IE: would the comments after the while loop, being outdented, still end the contents of the loop?)

Comment: @cHao, I would imagine no. Furthermore, I believe this solution will have the while loop run as intended, but it will still act as an infinite while loop until broken out of.

Answer (score 1):

```
  while True:            #What is this while loop means here
```

`while True` is an infinite loop.  Those loops are often used. If you write such a loop you **must** check in each iteration, whether the game has reached a condition to stop it manually. You can stop a loop from inside with the keyword `break`. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more details on control flow in python

In your code you probably want to a break at this point:

```
elif next=="open door" and bear_moved:
    gold_room()
    break
```

So, the loop will end if the door is open and the bear has moved.